# How do I print an object value inside a cout?

Tags: c++, class, instance

I have an object named `obj1`, and I have accessed an instance of class `New` (say `id`) using the `obj1` object. Eg, `obj1.id=500`;

Then I want to print out this statement: `"The name of id=500 is:"`, so how do I write the `obj1.id` value  inside the `cout` statement.

Comment: Please don't use sentences to describe existing code.  Use the code, so we know precisely what you're trying to ask.  Do you perhaps want `std::cout << "The name of id=" << obj1.id << " is:";`

Comment: Add your code, so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: `std::cout << "The name of id is " << obj1.id;`? Not sure if your just asking how to print, try looking this sort of thing up first: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: hey @paddy thank you for reaching out, my question is simple. I want to print an object value inside cout statement. (cout<<"The "obj1.id" is a bad guy";) like this. I want 500 to stay inside the cout

Answer (score 1):

To simply output the `id`, since it is a built-in type (int), you just chain each part of the message together as follows:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "The name of id=" << obj1.id << " is:";
    return 0;
}
```

But if you also want to output the raw **variable name**, you have to make use of preprocessor macros (see Wikitionary article [stringize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stringize#Usage_notes))

```cpp
// This can be used to generate a string from a variable name
#define NAME_OF_VARIABLE(var) #var

int main() {
    // Prints: "The name of id=500 is: obj1"
    std::cout << "The name of id=" << obj1.id << " is:" << NAME_OF_VARIABLE(obj1);
    return 0;
}
```